# Configuring WCF client gives the error "The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action

Tags: .net, wcf, configuration, client

My web service returns a error message no matter what configurations I set. I get the following error message.

> *The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/ITestingWebService/DoWork' is incorrect or
>   because the message contains an invalid or expired security context
>   token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security
>   context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due
>   to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions
>   prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's
>   binding.*

Here are my server & client `web.config` sections for WCF.

Server:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="ConnectedStoreCCM.TestingWebServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  httpGetUrl="" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"  />
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
         <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ITestingWebService" 
             openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
             transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152" maxBufferPoolSize="1024768">
            <readerQuotas 
                maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
            <security mode="None">
               <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
               <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false" 
                        establishSecurityContext="false" />
            </security>
         </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <services>
       <service behaviorConfiguration="ConnectedStoreCCM.TestingWebServiceBehavior"
                name="ConnectedStoreCCM.TestingWebService">
          <endpoint 
              address="" 
              binding="wsHttpBinding" 
              contract="ConnectedStoreCCM.ITestingWebService">
             <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
             </identity>
          </endpoint>
          <endpoint 
              address="mex" 
              binding="mexHttpBinding" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          <host>
             <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://www.someuri.net/supertest/TestingWebService.svc?wsdl" />
             </baseAddresses>
          </host>
       </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Client:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ITestingWebService" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false"
             maxBufferPoolSize="1024768"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <client>
      <endpoint name="WSHttpBinding_ITestingWebService" 
           address="http://www.someuri.net/supertest/TestingWebService.svc?wsdl"
           binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ITestingWebService"
           contract="ServiceReference1.ITestingWebService" >
         <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
         </identity>
      </endpoint>
   </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a service contract mismatch on the `ITestingWebService` interface. Try running a "Update Service Reference" by right clicking on the service reference in Visual Studio and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for Sixto for the suggestion, before i read you suggestion i think i found the cause of the problem with my WCF deployment.

Comment: I found the solution for the WCF service reference problem by myself. It is a deployment issue with a configuration element setting. I had to set the ServiceMetaData tags externalMetadataLocation to the machine name and the proper URL. The svcutil returned a web service address like http://ip-0aiquwe/Myservice.svc instead of http://www.mydomainname.net/Myservice.svc. When i set the externalMetadataLocaion="http://www.mydomainname.net/Myservice.svc"; It all worked well for me.